# How do I get to a value held by Box in pattern matching?

Tags: rust, enums

In trying to recall what I learnt last night from the third chapter of Rust By Example I've created an `enum` linked-list type this way:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum List {
    Nil,
    Cons(i32, Box<List>),
}
```

I've attempted attaching a `tail()` method to this type as follows:

```rust
impl List {
    // unrelated code not shown
    
    fn tail(&self) -> Self {
        match *self {
            Self::Cons(_, ref tail) => tail,
            nil => nil,
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> .\ee-enum-recall-linked-lists.rs:32:40
   |
30 |     fn tail(&self) -> Self {
   |                       ---- expected `List` because of return type
31 |         match *self {
32 |             Self::Cons(_, ref tail) => tail,
   |                                        ^^^^ expected enum `List`, found `&Box<List>`
   |
   = note:   expected enum `List`
           found reference `&Box<List>`
```

Which is baffling, because some other code I'd written in this same style to attach a `length()` method worked, and made me believe that the variable `tail` there is actually of type `List`.

```rust
impl List {
    // unrelated code not shown

    fn length(&self) -> i32 {
        match *self {
            Self::Cons(_, ref tail) =>  1 + tail.length(),
            _ => 0,
        }
    }
}
```

So, I'm wondering:

- What is the type of the value held by the variable `tail` there, really?
- Why does `tail.length()` work if `tail` isn't a `List`?
- How do I *match down* to the list contained in `tail`?

Comment: What is your intent with `List::tail`? It takes a reference, but returns a value. How do you intend to get this _owned_ value: steal from a non-mutable reference? Make a clone?

Comment: At this point of my Rust journey I'm working by constructing and deconstructing knowledge based on what I see my code do. @MatthieuM.'s comment has helped me dig deeper and realise that my former intuition for what `ref` is doing in that pattern matching was wrong -- and I've promptly updated my knowledge. I have working code now.

Comment: I am glad for you! If you have quick questions, you may find it easier to jump in the Rust chatroom: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust. There's all the usual suspects of the [tag:rust] tag, and the format is more "discussion" than formal question/answer, so it's a bit easier to get clarifications :)